# Windows 10 August Update KB5016616 returns 0x800f0922

Tags: windows-10

Few days ago Microsoft released a new update KB5016616. When Windows Update tries to install, after restarting the PC, Windows says "we couldn't apply the updates, rolling back". I tried every attempts I found but no result.

I re-installed Dotnet Framework 3.5 from Control Panel, I expanded System Reserved partition, I manually downloaded the update and tried to install, all ended with 0x800f0922. Tried to update by "Upgrade this PC" option from Microsoft, said "Thank you using for latest version of Windows". Any suggestions? A part of the log as below:

```
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0368109 12872 18112 ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0471111 12872 18112 ComApi          Byte length of the input buffer for deserialization: 4006245
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0904152 12872 18112 ComApi          Deserialized installable update 2022-x64 tabanl? Sistemler i?in Windows 10 Version 21H2 08 Toplu G?ncelle?tirmesi (KB5016616), UpdateID = {8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1}, CallbackInfo cookie length = 1880
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0905603 12872 18112 ComApi          Using handler to query deployment status for update 8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0906999 12872 18112 UDP             QueryUpdateDeploymentStatusInternal invoked in Readonly mode for Update : 8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0923630 12872 18112 Handler         Enter GetPostRebootResult for Deployment handler. Reporting cookie data:  {ProductName":"Client.OS.RS2.amd64"
2022.08.11 17:44:01.0925943 12872 18112 Handler         Sandbox folder C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ad9e650d01e9233632f32eacaeef810b exists
2022.08.11 17:44:01.1688194 12872 18112 Handler         Using the update's service stack dll file 'C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ad9e650d01e9233632f32eacaeef810b\Metadata\UpdateAgent.dll' 
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3862022 12872 18112 Handler         Update status code is 0x800F0922
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3862035 12872 18112 Handler         Failed to install the update
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3904197 12872 18112 Handler         Leave GetPostRebootResult for Deployment handler
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3904349 12872 18112 WIL             *FAILED* [80240FFF] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpreportingdata.cpp, line = 1098
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3905343 12872 18112 WIL             *FAILED* [80240FFF] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\dpreportingdata.cpp, line = 1075
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3905365 12872 18112 WIL             *FAILED* [80240FFF] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\engine\updatedeploymentprovider\lib\updatedeploymentprovider.cpp, line = 500
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3905453 12872 18112 UDP             *FAILED* [80240FFF] QueryUpdateDeploymentStatus exited with hr = 0x80240fff
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3905990 12872 18112 WIL             *FAILED* [80240FFF] file = onecore\enduser\windowsupdate\client\comapi\update.cpp, line = 4221
2022.08.11 17:44:01.3910012 12872 18112 ComApi          Reloading CUpdate 8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1 from datastore...
2022.08.11 17:44:01.5022931 12872 18112 ComApi          Deserializing update from serialized BSTR.
2022.08.11 17:44:01.5122354 12872 18112 ComApi          Byte length of the input buffer for deserialization: 4006245
2022.08.11 17:44:01.5564647 12872 18112 ComApi          Deserialized installable update 2022-x64 tabanl? Sistemler i?in Windows 10 Version 21H2 08 Toplu G?ncelle?tirmesi (KB5016616), UpdateID = {8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1}, CallbackInfo cookie length = 1880
2022.08.11 17:44:01.6012533 12872 18112 ComApi          Reload successful, UpdateID =  8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1, CallbackInfo cookie length = 1880, Current deployment action = 1, New deployment action = 1
2022.08.11 17:45:38.2254181 13424 4636  Shared          Power status changed
2022.08.11 17:45:38.2254621 13424 12084 DownloadManager Received power state change notification: Old: AC; New: AC.
2022.08.11 17:46:04.0098046 12872 18112 ComApi          Serializing CUpdate 8F56C3FA-2D4F-44E9-A392-76B839CDB970.1
2022.08.11 17:46:04.0326907 12872 18112 ComApi          Update serialization complete. BSTR byte length = 4006245, CallbackInfo cookie length = 1880
```

What I have done so far:

- Reset the Windows Update
- Rename SoftwareDistribution Folder
- Downloaded the update manually and installed from windows10.0-kb5016616-x64_94a65010a34b5bae2324c9433d1cae0b9d906d8c.msu
- Resized SystemReserved partition to 600mb
- Tried to install via Windows Udate Minitool
- Troubleshoot Windows Update
- Set App Readiness Service to Automatic (delayed)

Comment: Error 0x800f0922 occurs downloading the update usually means that you have less than 500 MB in system reserved partition. Verify in Disk Management if the partition is too small.

Comment: My system reserverd partition has 600mb total, 568mb free.

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot of Disk Management to your post?

Comment: @harrymc https://ibb.co/qdJPPFF also I've resized the partitions to make sure that I have more than 500mb free data. Before trying the update, I renamed SoftwareDistribution to something else, Windows created a new one, tried again and the same result.

Comment: A screenshot of the entire Disk Management window would be better.

Comment: You have reduced the image too much and made it unreadable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138477/discussion-between-ozkan-tuzemen-and-harrymc).

Comment: I had this exact issue, with the exact same error code (0x800f0922), and it ended up being that a required service wasn’t running.

Comment: @Ramhound 3 I've already set the service you mentioned as automatic but no success.

Comment: @OzkanTuzemen - in that case you might want to [edit] your question to include that vital information

Comment: @Ramhound found the issue and solution. Please check the question body.

Comment: @OzkanTuzemen - I have voted to reopen your question, you should submit an detailed answer, that includes all that necessary information to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

How I've resolved the problem:

I've checked the cbs.log (C:\Windows\Logs) as well and searched for "error" phrase. I've found that line:

`000005db BFSVC: 'Failed to get system partition! Last Error = 0x3bc3'`

I googled it and found that similar problems were experienced when the disk was converted from MBR to GPT. I converted my disk fom MBR to GPT as well a week ago, and I checked the partition list using diskpart. Partition list of the disk was like below:

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            600 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            929 GB   601 MB
  Partition 3    Primary           1300 MB   930 GB
```

I have here no system partition and somehow Windows was looking for the partition type to save the files.

I converted the partition 3 using this command:

```
select partition 3
SET ID=c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
```

Now the partition list is like below:

```
  Partition ###  Type              Size     Offset
  -------------  ----------------  -------  -------
  Partition 1    Primary            600 MB  1024 KB
  Partition 2    Primary            929 GB   601 MB
  Partition 3    System            1300 MB   930 GB
```

After rebooting I was able to complete the update.